# Binding errors in SSIS when importing from MySQL into SQL Server

Tags: mysql, ssis, ado.net, sql-server-2012

I am pretty new to SSIS and have inherited a very simple package that imports data from a MySQL database into a SQL Server table (OLE DB Destination). The MySQL developer gave me a new query to use in place of the one currently used in the Data Flow Component (ADO.NET Source) which allegedly provides the same output columns as before. I simply pasted it into the SqlCommand field in place of the existing query. But when I execute the package, I get five errors:

```
Error: 0xC002F445 at Data Import, OLE DB Destination [202]: An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "Column1" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT".
Error: 0xC002F446 at Data Import, OLE DB Destination [202]: An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "Column2" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT". The data flow column type is "DBBINDSTATUS_UNSUPPORTEDCONVERSION". The conversion from the OLE DB type of "DBTYPE_IUNKNOWN" to the destination column type of "DBTYPE_WVARCHAR" might not be supported by this provider.
Error: 0xC002F445 at Data Import, OLE DB Destination [202]: An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "Column3" column. The binding status was "DT_TEXT".
Error: 0xC002F445 at Data Import, OLE DB Destination [202]: An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "Column4" column. The binding status was "DT_TEXT".
Error: 0xC002F445 at Data Import, OLE DB Destination [202]: An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "Column5" column. The binding status was "DT_NUMERIC".
```

I am using SSIS in SQL Server 2012 SP1. Note that the AllowImplicitStringConversion is set to True in the ADO.NET Source. I had the MySQL developer give me a CSV of the result of running the query directly in MySQL so I could see what the data actually looks like.

1. For the first error (0xC002F445 for Column1), the DataType is **Unicode text stream [DT_NTEXT]** for both the External Columns section and the Output Columns section, and the destination SQL Server table is expecting an **NVARCHAR(max)**. What binding problem might I have?
2. For the second error (0xC002F446 for Column2) first, the DataType is **Unicode text stream [DT_NTEXT]** for both the External Columns section and the Output Columns section, and the destination SQL Server table is expecting an **NVARCHAR(15)**. The result set in the CSV has 'NULL' in this column for every row. I don't see why there is a problem, as we are trying to insert 4 characters into a 15 character column.
3. The next two columns have **Unicode string [DT_WSTR]** for both the External and Output types, and a **TEXT** type in the destination.
4. The last column is numeric **[DT_NUMERIC]** for both the External and Output types, and a **NVARCHAR(MAX)** type in the destination. Given that , I don't see why this is a problem.

Can anyone provide some guidance as to how I can resolve these issues?

By the way, what is the **[202]** in each error telling me?

Comment: I find for cases like this, an explicit cast to a specific data type and *length* can help tremendously. Otherwise, there's too many cooks in kitchen trying to get their data types to map from one to another. The other MySQL to SQL Server via SSIS advice I'd offer is to ensure you have, down the smallest grain, exact same driver across your organization. We ran into an issue where a point release from 12 to 13 caused the metadata to be treated differently and in incompatible ways.

Comment: Oddly, using either CAST or CONVERT in the query results in an error. I don't know MySQL, but surely it supports one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem when importing from an Excel file (Excel source) into OLE DB Destination, which gave me an error message like yours. It occured when there was a column in my Excel file that had more than 255 characters, which my package couldn't handle.

The solution for me was to just export the columns to a text file and import that instead.

Comment: I checked, and none of the values for the NVARCHAR columns were longer than 100 characters.